# adding "&" to .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a url which should be this one

```
http://127.0.0.1/search/d&r/
```

But when I add "&" to my .htaccess, I get the result as the same of this url,

```
http://127.0.0.1/search/d/
```

I can't use "&" in my urls, I tried everything but I cannot do it, here is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^([.//0-9a-zçöşığüA-ZÇÖŞİĞÜ&-]+)/$ tab.php?tab_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

Any idea how can I fix this ? thank you :)

Comment: Something is missing in your .htaccess file. There is no rule for the last conditions and where are you inserting `&` does not show either.

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA RewriteRule ^([.//0-9a-zçöşığüA-ZÇÖŞİĞÜ """&"""" -]+)/$ tab.php?tab_id=$1 [QSA,L]   It is here, thank you for answering :)

Comment: You should update your question so everybody can see it.

Comment: "&" is already there felipe

Comment: Yes. I didn't see it because the rewrite rule is before the conditions and thought it belonged to a different rule set. If it is the same rule set, it should be the last line, otherwise the conditions are doing nothing.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the htaccess. You just have to make sure that you are encoding the ampersand in your urls. So use `http://127.0.0.1/search/d%26r/` instead

Comment: @Gerben I encoded with urlencode to try, but i still get only d instead of d&r

Answer (score 0):

The ampersand should be encoded when put into the replacement url. To do this, use the [`B` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b).

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^([.//0-9a-zçöşığüA-ZÇÖŞİĞÜ&-]+)/$ tab.php?tab_id=$1 [QSA,L,B]
```

PS. Not sure what the RewriteCond's were for, but they always need to be placed before a RewriteRule.